# Leaking memory when assigning new value to variable?

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, new-operator, memory-leaks

Yes, I'm one of those fellows that is learning C++ coming from Java, being spoiled with an automatic garbage collector. There's a particular situation where I'm wondering whether I'm leaking memory or not. Let's consider in C++:

```
bool *test = new bool(false);
test = new bool(true);
delete test;
```

Am I leaking memory here? Or should I first call `delete` before assigning a new value? Like this:

```
bool *test = new bool(false);
delete test;
test = new bool(true);
delete test;
```

My gut feeling tells me the first is right, as the pointer `test` points at the same address in memory, and assigning a new value to its variable, will not change this address. Or does the `new` operator allocate a different address in memory? Can anyone give me a clue, or did I get it wrong all together?

Comment: Re: "Yes, I'm one of those fellows that is learning c++ coming from Java." Then I highly recommend picking up [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and pretend you've never learned Java. C++ is not Java. Attempting to program like Java in C++ will only lead to tears and frustration. [It's like using RegEx to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: "Spoiled" is a euphemism, if I have ever heard one.

Comment: It's quite possible that's exactly what he's doing.

Comment: Do you really need the 'bool' to be allocated on the heap? Especially single values of build-in types are very uncommon to be allocated on the heap. In a normal C++ program "new" is used much rarer than in a common Java program!

Comment: C++ has its own GC system that acts at a much finer grain than Javas. You just have to use it. Use `std::shared_ptr<int>` rather than `int*` and all your problems go away as the garbage collector now works. But you don;t even need to dynamically allocate the objects. Just use `bool` rather than `bool*`

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174725/how-do-you-explain-c-pointers-to-a-c-java-developer/5174827#5174827

Comment: @Martin: Can we please not suggest smart pointers?  You need to learn to walk before you can run.

Comment: @MGZero: I think that comment is silly. You should learn to use smart pointers first. When you have the basics down then you can experiment with the dangerous stuff like pointers. If we were learning C then my advice would be the other way around but C++ is **NOT** C nor should it be treated as such. Learning C first is (in my opinion) a mistake as you get in the wrong habits for developing C++ code.

Comment: @Martin: Although true raw pointers are more dangerous, I find it a bit strange to call smart pointers the basics as they're an implementation of raw pointers. Matter of opinion, I guess.

Comment: @MGZero: What are you talking about. `Smart pointers are an implementation of raw pointers` makes absolutely no sense. Using smart pointers rather RAW pointers makes pointer behave like pointers in nearly every other language (as the smart pointer is a wrapper object) and thus makes them intuitive to use for anybody coming from any other programming background (except C). How smart pointers are implemented is an irrelevant implementation details the fact they contains pointers is beside the point you do not need to know this to use them.

Comment: @MGZero: Since modern C++ code should contain zero (none nada not a single one) pointers I find it a waste of time teaching the concept of pointers to beginners (they need to learn to walk first). Once they understand the basics of how to use objects we can teach them how to use pointers to implement interesting objects (that;s when they learn to run with sharp pointy objects). I think you have your concept of running/walking completely backwards as it pertains to C++ usage (your ideas pertain to people that want to learn C).

Comment: @Martin Actually, it does make sense. You said it yourself, "as the smart pointer is a wrapper object." So you must agree obviously that behind the scenes of a smart pointer is a raw pointer (maybe I used the wrong word earlier). I also don't see how knowing how to use a pointer is irrelevant. Ask someone new to pointers to dereference their smart pointer, there's a good chance they won't have a clue what you're talking about. Just because the pointer is smart, doesn't mean the programmer is (sorry, it was there, I had to rofl).

Comment: @MGZero: No. Still does not make sense. Please feel free to join the [C++ chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec). There are currently several smart people in there that will explain the concepts.

Comment: @Martin If you're just going to say it doesn't make sense from this point on without any other reason and refer me to other people, then I'm not even going to waste our time. I was actually enjoying this little discussion of ours, btw.  Gave me something to do at work haha

Answer (score 6):

Yes you are leaking, and the c++ way to do it is:

```
bool test = false;
test = true; 

// ta-da - no leak.
```

You could do the second approach - however you're likely to draw lots of frowning...

Comment: and what if he needs to later `return test` ?

Comment: @amit, what's that got to do with anything?

Comment: @amit well, for built-in types I'd stick with Nim's option.

Comment: he probably uses dynamic allocation because static allocation cannot provide an answer. `return test` [or in your example `return &test`] will result in undefined behavior when later accessing `test`.

Comment: @amit: And why would a person return a reference to a local variable?

Comment: @hexa: so am I, but it seems like a toy example. the OP [or future reader] might understand from this answer that he should ALWAYS use static allocation, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: @In silicio: exactly what I meant, the OP is probably using dynamic allocation for a reason, the original example was NOT a local variable.

Comment: This answer implies one should always use static allocation instead of dynamic allocation. this is obviously not always possible, this is what I meant in my comments.

Comment: @amit - please read the answer carefully - did I mention *static* allocation anywhere? In C++ you should default to *stack* (read automatic) allocation where possible, and dynamic (through smart pointers) where not - the OP appears to be a beginner - smart pointers are probably a little way off yet... furthermore, to return a built-in type, I cannot think of any reason why you would return a dynamically allocated instance...

Comment: @amit: Correct. I think what Nim is trying to get at is that automatic allocation of variables are *preferable* to dynamic allocation.

Comment: @In Silicio, Nim: I agree static allocation is preferable when possible, but it is not always the case. it seems to me the OP is indeed a beginner, and he's currently learning dynamic allocation. a solution of "use static allocation" when learning dynamic allocation is not a solution, in my opinion.

Comment: @amit It seems more likely in my mind, that coming from reference-counted, garbage-collected, "new everything" Java, the OP isn't used to the idiomatic C++ way of declaring local variables.

Comment: @Kerrek SB - care to expand that comment?

Comment: @Nim: smart ass remark about the Standard not mentionning stack (apart from the STL structure) I'd guess :/

Comment: @Nim: C++ has no notion of "stack" and "heap" --  what matters is the storage class, "automatic" vs. "dynamic" (vs. "static"). Experienced C++ers are usually happy to conflate the two, but when talking to a recovering Java programmer I thought it'd be apropos to be clear about this.

Comment: @Kerrek - hehe - see, now your comment makes more sense to someone reading this far down in the comments! ;)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, exactly, you have to `delete` before you overwrite the address. Or better yet allocate on stack or use a smart pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You have indeed been spoiled.

The problem is that you do not differentiate between an address and a variable.

---

```
bool *test = new bool(false);
```

- Allocate space with automatic duration for `test`
- Allocate space with dynamic duration for a bool
- Write `false` into this space
- Store the address of this space into `test`

---

```
test = new bool(true);
```

- Allocate space with dynamic duration for a bool
- Write `true` into this space
- Store the address of this space into `test` (the address previously stored is ruthlessly discarded, since it is not stored anywhere else, the memory it points to can never be reclaimed, which means you have a leak).

---

```
delete test;
```

- Read the address stored into `test`
- Deallocate the space at this address

---

> My gut feeling tells me the first is right, as the pointer test points at the same address in memory, and assigning a new value to its variable, will not change this address. Or does the new operator allocate a different address in memory?

Semantically, you should consider that `new` always return an address to a `new` space in memory (Obviously false, as memory is reused). This is why each call to `new` need to be matched by *exactly one* call to `delete`.

Therefore your gut feeling is wrong, `new` does not create "just" a variable. If you are coming from Java, this may be shocking indeed, and you'll need a strong tutorial to grasp the finer points of programming.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are leaking memory. For every `new` there should be a subsequent `delete`. If you overwrite a pointer with a new address then you lose the opportunity to pair the allocation with a `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your first example is actually leaking memory. *Every* call to `new` must have a matched call to `delete` (unless the `new` failed).

In C++ the normal way to do what you appear to be trying to do is to simply declare the bool locally:

```
bool b = truel
b = false;
```

If however you actually need dynamic allocation for some reason, there are smart pointers that manage the memory so you don't have to worry about calling `delete`. You can look up `scoped_ptr`, `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.

Finally, C++ has a great standard library that handles many possible containers and algorithms, preventing you from having to reinvent them and saving you from having to deal with dynamic allocation in a wide variety of cases.

If you're serious about learning C++ I would pick out one of the books from the SO C++ book list and learn from the ground up rather than trying to transfer Java idioms to C++ (it just won't work well).

Answer (score 0):

bool is a built in datatype.Why do you need to allocate memory like that?You can easily allocate on stack

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are leaking memory in the first case.  The second way is the proper way to do it.  In your first case...

When you call new the second time, the first allocation goes out of scope, but still exists.  In Java, this is fine because the GC will clean it up for you.  However, in C++, there's no such way with raw spointers.

Each call to new must also have a call to delete at some point.  Also, after you delete a pointer, set it to null or 0.  This will prevent you from accidently deleting invalid memory.