# Using Integer in Switch Statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

For various business reasons I want to hold some static IDs in one of my classes. They were originally `int` but I wanted to change them to `Integer` so I could do an equals on them (ie `MY_ID.equals(..)` which avoids NPEs)

When I change them to Integer I get errors in my switch statement. The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) say that Integer should be ok within Switches.

To quote

> [Switch] also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types),
>   the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain
>   primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in
>   Numbers and Strings).

In my code below if i is a `int` then it compiles. When it is an `Integer` it doesnt saying that a `constant expression is required`. I have tried doing `.intValue()` but this doesnt work either.

Am I being really stupid? Or completely misreading the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)?

```
private static final Integer i = 1;

@Test
public void test() {
    switch(mObj.getId()){
        case i: //do something
        default: //do something default
    }

}
```

Thanks for any pointers here. For the time being I am keeping them as `int` and doing `new Integer(myint).equals(...)`

Comment: I'll suggest you to use enums. They're really appropriate for this case.

Comment: yes I agree @dystroy. These IDs are matching ids in the database which is why we are using this. I suppose we could use enums though...

Comment: I also use enums matched in DB, there is no problem. enums are really powerful in java now.

Comment: I just want to clarify that primitive types, like int, cannot throw Null Pointer Exceptions (NPEs) in Java, only object references can. So using int should still be a viable option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change your constant to primitive type:

```
private static final int i = 1;
```

and you'll be fine. `switch` can only work with primitives, enum values and (since Java 7) strings. Few tips:

- `new Integer(myint).equals(...)` might be superflous. If at least one of the variables is primitive, just do: `myint == ...`. `equals()` is only needed when comparing to `Integer` wrappers.
- Prefer `Integer.valueOf(myInt)` instead of `new Integer(myInt)` - and rely on autoboxing whenever possible.
- Constant are typically written using capital case in Java, so `static final int I = 1`.

Comment: To be precise: the `switch` variable can be char, byte, short, integer, enum and String (and corresponding Object). But the `case` values must be constants, i.e. a primitive type, enum value or compile-time String.

Comment: what if you must use it like in this code: public class SwitchOca {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  final String x = "0";
  final String y = new String("0");
  switch(x) {
   case y:
    System.out.println("error ...");
    break;
   case "2":
    System.out.println("primitive ...");
    break;
  }
 }
}

Answer (score 3):

Switch [require constant expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) in the `case` statements or enum constants. [A constant expression is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28):

> an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly

So Integers don't qualify. In your case, you can either use an `int` or an enum (which would make sense if your IDs are known at compile time).

The only place where you can use a boxed type (for example an Integer) is in the switch expression:

```
switch(Integer.valueOf(1)) {
    case 1: //
}
```

Comment: To quote the docs linked in my questions `It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types), the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in Numbers and Strings).` Am I misunderstanding what it is saying?

Comment: @RNJ That only applies to the expression in `switch(expression)`, not to the case statements.

Comment: Though I find it interesting that the Integer isn't autoboxed to int in the case statement. I would expect that, but I have never tried it. Even with the compile time constant, i is final, so the compiler should know it will always be 1, but I suppose autoboxing isn't done until runtime. (not arguing with you, just surprised)

Answer (score 3):

Now that java offers enums, we usually do it like this :

```
public enum MyKey {
   i,
   j
}

...

switch(mObj.getId()){
    case i: //do something
    default: //do something default
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because I was looking at this...

The accepted answer says that:

> switch can only work with primitives, enum values and (since Java 7)
>   strings

However,

[14.11 The switch Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11)

outlines the JavaSE7 documentation for switch that shows:

> The type of the Expression must be char, byte, short, int, **Character, Byte, 
>   Short, Integer**, String, or an enum type (§8.9), or a compile-time error
>   occurs.

I just wanted to clarify for future surfers.

Comment: To be precise: the `switch` variable can be char, byte, short, integer, enum and String (and corresponding Object). But the `case` values must be constants, i.e. a primitive type, enum value or compile-time String.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a constant value in a switch statement.

```
switch(mObj.getId()){
    case 5: //do something
    default: //do something default
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code shown 'i' is an object pointer, not a constant expression.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't want to offend you or sound rude. I just meant that what is called *pointer* in C/C++ is named *reference* in Java (sort-of). Check out [1](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/141834), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92001), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185462), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080617) and [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174725). It's just a naming convention used among Java developers.