# Use of Integer type in Switch statement in java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I was writing some simple code in java for my android app and i got these errors.

`case expressions must be constant expressions` while `private static final Integer` is constant

```
private static final Integer INVALID_USER = 901;
private static final Integer SENDING_FAILED = 902;
private static final  Integer OK = 903;
/*
 *
 *  And some more project related declaration...
 *
 */


        switch (responseCode){
            case INVALID_USER:

                    // logout
                    break;

            case SENDING_FAILED:

                    //resend request
                    break;

            case OK:
                    break;
        }
```

This is because i used `Integer Type`, then i changed type to `int` and problem is solved

My question is why we cant use `Integer` as a case expression. [Docs says  " A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types), the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) though variable is constant
I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603824/using-integer-in-switch-statement) but didnt get any thing

Comment: I already gave link of that question but i didnt get my asnwer

Comment: that question just solves the answer and does not give explanation

Comment: switch can only work with primitives, enum values and (since Java 7) strings.

Comment: Are you missing ; after 903 on purpose?

Comment: nope its just a mistake in copy paste

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***Constant expressions*** are used as case labels in switch statements (
>   §14.11 ) and have a special significance for assignment conversion (
>   §5.2 ) and .....

[`Definition of Constant Expression §15.28`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)

> *A compile-time constant expression is an expression denoting a value
>   of **primitive type** or a **String** that does not complete abruptly.*

Now in above scenario compiler is looking for *constant expression* as it should be know to the compiler at the compile time.As stated `Integer` is actually not a constant Expression for the compiler.

Comment: ohh thats why it is giving compile time error

Answer (score 2):

The Docs lines "Docs says : A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types), the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer"
is for

```
switch(expressions used here)
```

and not with `case` statement.

You can use primitive type `int` with `case` and then `Integer.valueOf(your_int_value);` where ever you want it as a `Integer`

Answer (score -2):

java does not allow to use Object into the switch. we can use byte, int, char and enumerated  value as a switch expression. in jdk1.7  we can use String as a switch expression. to do this for wraper Class object you need to use valueOf method of wrapper class

```
private static final Integer INVALID_USER = 901;
private static final Integer SENDING_FAILED = 902;
private static final  Integer OK = 903;
/*
 *
 *  And some more project related declaration...
 *
 */


        switch (responseCode){
            case INVALID_USER.valueOf():

                    // logout
                    break;

            case SENDING_FAILED.valueOf():

                    //resend request
                    break;

            case OK.valueOf():
                    break;
        }
```

Comment: The syntax is incorrect